# Merge two rows and form column header for Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas data frame as  the following:

```
    0      1             2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    ...    
0      USAF   WBAN  YR--MODAHRMN  DIR  SPD  GUS  CLG  SKC    L    M   ...     
1       NaN    NaN           GMT  NaN  MPH  MPH  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   ...     
2    444540  99999  201801010000  ***    0  ***  722  SCT    *    *   ...     
3    444540  99999  201801010050  ***    0  ***   30  ***    *    *   ...     
4    444540  99999  201801010150  990    2  ***  100  ***    *    *   ...     
5    444540  99999  201801010250  ***    0  ***  100  ***    *    *   ...
```

I want to merge the first two rows, remove NaN values and make it a  column header as following:

```
      USAF   WBAN  YR--MODAHRMN  DIR   SPD  GUS  CLG  SKC    L    M   ...     
                            GMT        MPH  MPH                      ...     
0    444540  99999  201801010000  ***   0  ***  722  SCT    *    *   ...     
1    444540  99999  201801010050  ***   0  ***   30  ***    *    *   ...
```

Is there a way I can correctly do it?

Comment: Is the dataframe the output of a `read_csv`? If so, you are better off with `read_csv(filename, header=[0,1])`.

Comment: It is an HTML file. But, it still solved my problem. Thank you